# Taking inventory of VS Code Extensions across multiple computers?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

If you have multiple developers w/ multiple developer workstations and they each have VS Code, how can I track what extensions that have from a central location?  I don't want to have to sign on to each workstation one at a time and pull up VS Code for a list of installed extensions and versions. FOr example, there is a vulnerability in VS Code's TS-Lint extension.  How can I tell what computers in my group have that installed?

Answer (score 0):

### Method 1: Query the File System

The [Common Questions section of the page Managing Extensions in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_common-questions) shows where extensions are installed:

> Where are extensions installed?
>
> Extensions are installed in a per user extensions folder. Depending on your platform, the location is in the following folder:
>
> - Windows: %USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions
> - macOS: ~/.vscode/extensions
> - Linux: ~/.vscode/extensions

The `extensions` directory contains one subdirectory for each installed extension, named like `(extension)-(version)`.  Listing its contents for each user and machine should provide a comprehensive list of installed extensions.

### Method 2: Query VSCode Itself

Another approach is to use the VSCode command line as explained in the [Command Line Extension Management](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_command-line-extension-management) of that same page.  In particular, you can run:

```
$ ./bin/code --list-extensions --show-versions
```

from the VSCode install directory when logged in as a particular user to get a list of `(extension)@(version)` strings.

But note: you have to use the `code` program in the `bin` subdirectory of VSCode, which is a shell script (requiring Cygwin on Windows).  On Windows at least, there is also `Code.exe` in the top-level VSCode directory, but that one does not respect those command line flags.